# Use audio port to send digital messages

Tags: audio, computer-science

I want to take a casette tape and store digital messages and maybe even files on a traditional cassette tape. I also want the computer to read the messages/files back through the microphone port. Is this possible, and if so, how can I do this and is there software available to do this? I am not expecting instantaneous large files, I just want to do this as a fun project

Thanks,
Skyler

Comment: My Vic-20 could do it!

Comment: I wasn't even alive 10 years after that computer came out!!

Comment: you are using the same technology in a modem. Look up information about modulation (Amplitude, frequency and phase modulation), as well as error checking and correcting codes.